# strange problem with disk D&S are hidden

Tags: windows, hard-drive

After a several crashes my laptop don't want to startup. I believe it has disk problems

When I mounted the disk external, C:\Documents and Settings folder properties showed hidden and 0 bytes of size.

Shouldn't the folder C:\Documents and Settings be hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try mounting it in a way that ignores filesystem permissions (e.g. linux live dvd).  The user you are mounting the partition as might not have appropriate permissions for that particular drive....does chkdsk /F from recovery console report any errors?

Comment: ok, allthough it was a fat32 disk, never worked with those live cd's before, time to learn. The disk was loaded with trojans and stuff. (109 pieces of  junk)

Comment: my answer is not valid for fat32 only ntfs...thanx for the check but i don't deserve it on this one.  getting permission denied on fat32 your disk is irrevocabbly hosed

Comment: I see, you brought me on ideas :D